# Is it valid to write [(m + n)^m] / m! as O([n / m]^m) as its loose upper bound?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, upperbound

While writing the upper bound of **[(m + n)^m] / m!** as **O([n / m]^m)** , I have considered that **m! = O(m^m)** .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming; try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @kaya3 While (I think) it's on topic at cs, it should not be off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

As you said `m!` is `o(m^m)`. Hence, you can't replace it in `A = (m+n)^m / m!` to get an upper bound! Instead you can using Stirling's approximation to get a proper upper bound. As we have (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)):

```
m! = \sqrt{2\pi m} (m/e)^m (1 + O(1/m))
```

You can get an upper bound for `A`, by replacing `m!` with `(m/e)^m`. Hence:

```
A < (n+m)^m / (m/e)^m = (e*(n+m)/m)^m = (e * (n/m + 1))^m
```

if `n > m`, we know `(n/m + 1)^m = Theta((n/m)^m)`. Therefore, `A \in O(e^m (n/m)^m)`

Answer (score 1):

It is not.

---

**Reason:** In the expression ((m + n)<sup>m</sup>) / m!, the value "m!" is the denominator.

In a fractional number, increasing the denominator makes the number smaller. Example: The number 4 is greater than 3. So, when put in denominator, 1/4 is smaller than 1/3<sup>*</sup>.

In case of fractional values, to get a looser upper bound you can do two things:

1. Increase the numerator; and/or,
2. Decrease the denominator.

Since in your approximation:

- you are making the denominator looser; therefore,
- you are actually increasing the denominator; therefore,
- you are reaching a smaller fraction value;

lending you a tighter bound, not a looser one.

---

<sup>** Primary school mathematics here:  Dividing a pizza in four equal parts and getting one slice vs dividing the pizza in three equal parts and getting the one big slice - you get more pizza when dividing amongst only 3 people.*</sup>